# Invisible mirror modifier?

Tags: modifiers

For some weird reason, only this object acts like it has a mirror modifier when it clearly does not.

[image]

Painting acts with symmetry, as well as the UV map. When painting, I turned off x-symmetry and it still clones to the other side. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: is it possible that one half is mirrored and below the other one in the uv editor?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: assuming that the missing uv-half is identical (but mirrored) to the visible right one, could it be that the uv-halves are overlapping? Can you select one vertex of the uv and move it, if an identical vertex lies under the moved one... but just guessing :)

Comment: Oh dear, you're right! Is there a way to fix this, without manually moving each vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 3d-viewport select only those 3d-faces you want to seperate in the uv-editor. Then only these faces appear in the uv-editor.

Next you select all appearing faces (<kbd>a</kbd>) in the uv-editor, scale them using <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>, so the faces get mirrored and grab them (<kbd>g</kbd>) to place them where you want them to be.